# 500 internal error on SharePoint. - SharePoint 2010 and .NET SSO causing

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, iis, sharepoint-2010, web-config

I am having some trouble getting my setup working. I have a .NET application set to `claims.mydomain.com` and my SharePoint 2010 app set to `sharepoint.mydomain.com` I am able to login to both applications separately using the active directory membership provider. However, if I log into the .NET application and then move to the SharePoint I get an error saying `500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR`

Here is the current entry to my .NET application's web.config

```
     <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="30"
         name=".ASPXAUTH"  path="/" slidingExpiration="true"
         defaultUrl="default.aspx" cookieless="UseCookies"
         enableCrossAppRedirects="true"
         domain=".mydomain.com" />
```

Entry to my SharePoint web.config.

```
<forms loginUrl="/_login/default.aspx" protection="All" timeout="30"
         name=".ASPXAUTH"  path="/" slidingExpiration="true"
         defaultUrl="default.aspx" cookieless="UseCookies"
         enableCrossAppRedirects="true"
         domain=".mydomain.com" />
```

machineKey for both are exactly the same:

```
<machineKey validationKey="value" 
            decryptionKey="value"
            validation="SHA1" 
            decryption="AES" />
```

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: What are the details of the "internal server error" you get?  You need to debug that further.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have a problem with either the web.config of your application of the web.config of the Claims Authentication service.

If you can use the browser directly in the server through remote desktop as more info about what went wrong will be provided.

Alternatively you will need to ask an administrator to provide more details about the error in the IIS or application event logs

Comment: Thanks Luis. I am actualy using the browser directly from my remote desktop and that's the only error message I get. I tried enabling all custom errors but I cannot seem to get any more details.